# SQL Query using outer join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have the following relations:

[image]

and I want to to list all employees that joined the company before June of 2014 but did not receive a commission in June 2014 using some kind of outer join. I came up with this query but it is not working. Could someone tell me how to query this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee.EmpId, Employee.EmpName
FROM Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN Commission
ON Employee.EmpId = Commission.EmpId
WHERE Employee.JoinDate BETWEEN Employee.JoinDate AND '2014-06-31'
GROUP BY Employee.EmpId, Employee.EmpName
HAVING COUNT(Commission.Commdate BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-31') = 0
ORDER BY Employee.EmpId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` is a good idea.  But, you want the commission dates in the `ON` clause.  Then find the employees that do not match.  So, here is a version of the query (cleaned up to use table aliases):

```
SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName
FROM Employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Commission c
     ON e.EmpId = c.EmpId AND
        c.Commdate BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-31'
WHERE e.JoinDate < '2014-06-01' AND c.EmpID IS NULL
GROUP BY e.EmpId, e.EmpName
ORDER BY e.EmpId;
```

Perhaps a more natural way to write the query, though, is:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Commission c
                  WHERE e.EmpId = c.EmpId AND
                        c.Commdate BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-31'
                 ) AND
       e.JoinDate < '2014-06-01';
```